# How can I show popup with slimbox on page load only for the first visit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, slimbox

So far my idea was to implement a function popup("url") checking for an existing cookie which is triggered by loading the body of the page (onLoad - not a nice solution I know). I used the exact code from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) to implement cookie functionality which I included in my application.js . There I also included my `popup()` function:

```
   function popUp(startimage) {
    var x = readCookie('ecocrowd')
    if (x = 'nopopup') {
    }
    else {
        jQuery.slimbox(startimage);
    }

}
```

In the html-template for my start page I included the following parts:

```
<body onLoad="popup("wirdiezukunft.png")">
```

and

```
<script>createCookie('ecocrowd','nopopup',7)</script>
```

Am I missing something out? It is the first time I am working with a Javascript implementation like this so I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance!

update (content of createcookie() ):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {


    if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/

Comment: `if (x = 'nopopup')` should be `if (x == 'nopopup')`

Comment: Please note down @Pete's point and still if it doesn't work then make sure whether the cookie is set, if not--update the `createCookie` function in this question.

Comment: @NishantGhodke updated the question with create Cookie function - Pete 's hint couldn't fix it thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Forget cookies, use [localStorage](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) as it has a much more practical interface, and no weird stuff with paths, expirations and domains:

```
if(!window.localStorage.getItem('hasShown')) {
  showMyPopup();
  window.localStorage.setItem('hasShown', true);
}
```

There is actually a much more practical interface for cookies in HTML5 but it isn't as widely supported as localStorage yet.

Comment: so instead of showMyPopup(); I would simply insert my function jQuery.slimbox("image.jpg"); ? I never worked with localStorage so I am not sure how to handle it. Would I paste this code as script in my html template? Thanks for your help!